# iCarousel AVPlayerItem Instances not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, avplayer, icarousel

**What I am trying to achieve**

I would like to display a carousel of videos that play independently. No more than 10 at a time. as well as having their own play button per carousel object to play independently.

**What I am getting**
After 3 Items display in the carousel it displays the same three over and over again until it reaches the end of the 10 items.

I am assigning the AVAsset like below:

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_videoURLS objectAtIndex:index]] options:nil];
```

_videoURLS is an NSMutableArray of NSStrings it returns a 10 count to populate 10 items in the carousel like below.

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfItemsInCarousel:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
//return the total number of items in the carousel
return [_videoURLS count];
}
```

Now to populate the Video View I am doing the below:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_videoURLS objectAtIndex:index]] options:nil];


//create new view if no view is available for recycling
if (view == nil)
{
    //don't do anything specific to the index within
    //this `if (view == nil) {...}` statement because the view will be
    //recycled and used with other index values later
    UIView *mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 370.0f)]; 
    view = mainView;
    CGFloat mainViewWidth = mainView.bounds.size.width;

    //Video Player View
    _videoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, mainViewWidth, 220)];
    _videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:123/255.0 blue:123/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    _videoView.center = CGPointMake(100, 170);//170
    _videoView.tag = 20;
    [view addSubview:_videoView];

    //AV Asset Player
    AVPlayerItem * playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];
    playerLayer.frame = _videoView.bounds;
    [_videoView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
    [_player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];


    //Play Button
    _playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0f, 60.0f)];
    [_playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play-icon-grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    _playButton.center = CGPointMake(100, 160);
    _playButton.tag = 1;
    [view addSubview:_playButton];


}
else
{
    //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
    _playButton = (UIButton *) [view viewWithTag:1];
    _videoView = (UIView *) [view viewWithTag:20];
}

//set item label
//remember to always set any properties of your carousel item
//views outside of the `if (view == nil) {...}` check otherwise
//you'll get weird issues with carousel item content appearing
//in the wrong place in the carousel

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinishPlaying:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_player];

return view;
}
```

I handle the play button like below:

```
-(IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
if (_playButton.isHidden) {
    [_playButton setHidden:NO];
}else{
    [_playButton setHidden:YES];
    [_player play];
}
}
```

Though when I press the play button it plays the second video in the carousel.
What is the proper way to handle this and have all the videos play single handed?

Comment: I seriously need help with this so if anyone thinks they can help me or has seen this issue before please help me!!!!